# How do I classify my Shadowstep Rogue lvl 40's damage?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a level 40 human Shadowstep rogue. For a long time I've been wondering if he does good damage. In the quests that I do (appropriate to my level) I have no problem at all defeating my enemies. Dueling against 5 level higher people isn't a problem either, because Shadowstep and ambush take them out quickly. I have 1 sword (27.5dps) and a mace (29dps) equipped. One of them does additional damage because it's in the main hand, which brings me to about 100dps with both weapons.

In dungeons I can take out various 4-5k elites by myself, and my shadowstep/ambush (or garotte) combination usually does 700-900+ damage, followed by some 200-400 criticals because of the -70% armor. Dmg/hit is around 180-200. Sometimes I feel like I'm doing a lot less damage than other players, like warrior-tanks or shapeshifted druids.

Am I doing a small, medium or high amount of damage for my level and class?

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but as long as you're not having trouble killing enemies and completing quests, you're doing *fine*. Comparing one class's damage output to another  (at anything other than max level) is kind of an apples-to-oranges thing.

Comment: @Brant - I'd even post that as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you're making a contribution to the group and not just afk auto-attacking mobs, don't worry about DPS until you hit the level cap.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this as 'how do i evaluate my damage', weapon dps ratings don't really matter, nor does what the weapon hits for individually. Its what you do in a particular fight consistently.

For this you need some sort of a damage meter such as recap or skada, or if you really care to get into it worldoflogs client.

Another issue is that if you are stunlocking, kicking or otherwise supporting a group, that should be noted and those fights removed from your trends.

So if you are doing Sm Armory in a group, and on all the trash elites you are pulling 120dps, with 98% attendance, 12% miss rate, etc. I would say thats pretty good, likely your getting a buff or two from your group as well. That's what I would expect from a one button single target macro mage.

If your significantly lower than that, I would suspect your rotation priority are to blame, also new rogues have a problem baning their combo points for killing blows that get stolen by other characters in a group, or they don't know how to deal with large health pools on mobs so the build up combo points and then unload damage, forgetting things like slice and dice, bleed, and so forth.

If you suspect you are leaving combo points on dead mobs, there are addons to tell you that. If you consistently have 4 or 5 combo points left on a mob, you need to revisit your style.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost always going to do more damage to regular mobs than elite mobs. The elites have far more defense and resistances than your regular quest mobs do, most of the time. [Shadowstep](http://www.wowpedia.org/Shadowstep) does not appear to affect damage type.

Comment: For future reference, I'd suggest wowpedia instead of wowwiki. I believe most of the editors from the latter have moved to the former.

Comment: I'm long out of WoW for my own good. I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend to you

1. Use recount (addon) and calculate your DPS at the end of a dungeon.
2. Post that DPS score on this website and let other users try and help you.
3. Most importantly stop worrying about your DPS **now** your level 40, while it is good your conscious of your DPS it should never be a problem until you get to level 85 and are participating in end-game content. That is when you should be focused on pushing your DPS by getting gear.